# Confused on how to write .map method with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to understand how to add TypeScript to my .map method, but at the moment, I'm getting the following error message.  I'm not really sure what the 'never' keyword signifies either.

```
TS2339: Property 'fname' does not exist on type 'never'
```

The code I'm using is:

```
const [climbs, setClimbs] = useState([]);
...
useEffect(() => {
  async function data() {
    try {
      const getClimbs = await axios.get("http://localhost:4000/climbs");
      setClimbs(getClimbs.data);
    } catch (err) {}
  }
  data();
}, []);
...
<div className="list">
  {climbs.map(climb => {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="list-name">{climb.fname}</div>
        <div className="list-recent-climb">
          {climb.climb} - {climb.grade} - {climb.location}
        </div>
        <div className="list-date">{climb.date}</div>
      </>
    );
  })}
</div>
...
```

I also tried adding a type object at the top to see if that would clear things up.  I'm new to TypeScript so trying to get my bearings.

```
type Props = {
  fname: String,
  climb: String,
  grade: String,
  location: String,
  date: Date
}
```

Comment: You should share a bit more code, specifically the parts where `climbs` is created.

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @Evert How/why are you considering this to be a duplicate.  I don't see anywhere on that linked question about TypeScript or the .map array method, which is specific to my question.

Comment: Sorry, it was still only a partial sample, so I jumped to the conclusion that you were using a variable before it was available. Sorry if that was a wrong assumption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are calling `useState` with an empty array which defaults to type `never[]`. Change it to:

```
React.useState<Props[]>([])
```

Comment: Or `React.useState([] as Props[])`

Comment: Thank you, that worked.  Now I just need to learn why that is.

Comment: Are familiar with type generics?

Comment: I'm not, but just read up on it.  It sounds like you are making a generic start so that you can use any kind of type for later.  Does that not go against the point of TypeScript?

Comment: The compiler can't infer the type of your empty array just by looking in other locations how you might be using . You have to let TypeScript know what they type of your empty array is so that it can properly infer the usage of `useState`